# html, основы, скрипты

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как можно вставить картинку в ячейку таблицы с помощью js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`td` - это `id` ячейки:

`document.getElementById(td).innerHTML += '<img src='адрес..'></img>';`

Можно еще сделать картинку как фон.

```
document.getElementById(td).style.backgroundImage = 'url(адрес)'
```

Comment: А это единственный способ?

Comment: @Юрий нет. А вам чем-то не нравится этот?

Comment: @D-side мне он каким-то колхозным кажется, добавлять код, как строку, может, я не привык пока :D

Comment: @Юрий Верно мыслите! Можно не строкой.

Comment: @D-side а как не строкой?

Answer (score -4):

`td` - это `id` ячейки:

```
document.getElementById(td).innerHTML += '<img src='адрес..'></img>';
```

Советую вам использовать Bootstrap для избежание излишних затрат сил

Comment: может вы с jquery спутали в ремарке про bootstrap?